# Enterprise Library 4.1 database logging stored procedure failed

Tags: database, logging, enterprise-library

I'm using Enterprise Library 4.1, Visual Studio 2008, SQL Server 2008 and I'm logging errors to database using database trace listener.

In my development system, everything is working fine but in live system, it is not working properly.

There is no problem with permissions -- I'm sure there is some error in the stored procedure.

Is there any way to trace the stored procedure error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much to go on in your question.

But as a start I would check that you have the error source configured to use a **non-database** listener (e.g. flat file or Event Log).  If you are using a configuration file it would look like:

```
<listeners>
  <add source="Logging Quick Start" formatter="Text Formatter"
    log="" machineName="." listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    name="Event Log Destination" />
</listeners>
<specialSources>
  <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Event Log Destination" />
    </listeners>
  </errors>
</specialSources>
```

If (or once) you have that set up then try to log something to the database listener and check to see if you are getting any errors logged indicating why the database listener is not working.

If I were to guess I would put my money on some sort of connection issue.

If you think the problem is with SQL then you can start the [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) to trace the SQL Server activity.  You should be able to see the connection coming in and the SQL being executed.  If you don't see any activity for the connection and stored procedure then you know that SQL Server is not being called.  This would mean that the issue is not with SQL Server/stored procedure but with the code, configuration, permissions, firewall, etc.

Comment: Hi, im sure there is no problem with the connection as rest of my site is working. Do we need to give any permissions for database logging. Im not sure about the permissions. Anyway let me check using SQL Server Profiler.